# Could the Duplicate Silver Blood Crew of Voyager have become ignorant or damaged early on by the huge Mutara Nebula from episode "One"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I'm re-watching Voyager. In the "Demon" episode of Season 4 Voyager needs to make a landing on a weird small planet because of fuel emergency. Eventually the crew gets duplicated and real Voyager lifts-off.

In the next episode – "One" – The Real Voyager crew is in suspended animation for 5 weeks to protect them from dangerous radiation from a huge Mutara Nebula which Janeway really wants to cross.

But in Season 5 episode "Course: Oblivion" there is no mention of this huge nebula. How is this possible?  Was the duplicate crew/ship badly damaged by the nearby nebula and causing all sorts of memory loss?

Comment: We don't know. Just because they didn't mention the nebula, doesn't mean they didn't encounter it. They didn't mention 90% of the missions/worlds/species Voyager had encountered by that point.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately there is no canon answer to this, with that being said it is completely plausible that the nebula did not do anything to the duplicate crew or ship, IIRC the new warp drive produced some kind of radiation that would not have harmed humans but did cause damage to the duplicates so the nebulae radiation could have damaged humans but caused the duplicates absolutely no discomfort.